# PDFTK want to transfer to another domain

Tags: php, pdf-generation, pdftk

I am working on a project which was developed by another developer
Now client wants me to move it from current linux based server to new windows based server

it is developed in cakephp 
and PDFTK is used to fill pdf files dynamically.

I am trying to configure it first on my PC locally, to learn configuration of PDFTK

I have downloaded PDFTK Free version and installed

it generates pdfile with zero bytes size and it is not opeining

I also tried to try in in CMD

```
pdftk D:\wamp\www\my-project\app\webroot/files/138.pdf fill_form D:\wamp\www\my-project\app\webroot/files/results/1401.fdf output generated_pdfs/test_24.pdf
```

it returns the following error

```
 Error: Failed to open output file:
   generated_pdfs/test_24.pdf
   No output created.
 Error: unable to open file for output: generated_pdfs/test_24.pdf
```

while the target folder has permission to write on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pdftk TEMPLATE_FILE fill_form DATA_FILE output OUTPUT_FILE
```

try using OUTPUT_FILE with fullpath as below

```
OUTPUT_FILE = D:/folder/.../generated_pdfs/test_24.pdf
```